# Memory corruption using clEnqueueWriteBuffer - OpenCL

Tags: c++, c, arrays, opencl, memory-corruption

I'm working in some code that sends large amounts of data from host to device, and it behaves erratically.

In the following piece of the code, I'm trying to send from host to device an array. 
The array size is incrementing on each iteration, gradually increasing the amount of memory sent to the device. 
The first element in the array is filled with a nonzero value, and it's read from inside the kernel and printed to console. 
The value should be the same when it's read from the host and from the device, but in some iterations it's not.

Here's the code:

```
    int SizeArray = 0;

    for(int j=1; j<100 ;j++){ 

        //Array memory allocation, starting with 4MB in first iteration to 400MB in last one
        SizeArray = j * 1000000 * sizeof(float);
        Array = (float*)malloc(SizeArray);
        memset(Array, 0, SizeArray);

        //Give the array's first element some nonzero value
        //This is the value that is expected to be printed by the kernel execution
        Array[0] = j;

        memArray = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, SizeArray, NULL, &ret);

        //Write the array contents into the buffer inside the device
        ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, memArray, CL_TRUE, 0, SizeArray, Array, 0, NULL, NULL);
        ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&memArray);

        getchar();

        //Execute the kernel where the content of the first element of the array will be printed
        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 3, NULL, mGlobalWorkSizePtr, mLocalWorkSizePtr, 0, NULL,NULL);
        ret = clFinish(command_queue);

        /****** FAIL! Kernel prints correct value of Array's first element ONLY IN 
        SOME ITERATIONS (when it fails zero values are printed)! Depending on SizeArray :?? ******/

        free(Array);
        ret = clReleaseMemObject(memArray);
    }
```

The device where this code was tested has the following features:

```
- Name:                    Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
- DeviceVersion:           OpenCL 1.1 
- DriverVersion:           8.15.10.2696
- MaxMemoryAllocationSize: 425721856
- GlobalMemoryCacheSize:   2097152
- GlobalMemorySize:        1702887424
- MaxConstantBufferSize:   65536
- LocalMemorySize:         65536
```

Kernel prints incorrect values or not, depending on the buffer size sent to the device.

Here's the output:

```
Array GPU: 1.000000
Array GPU: 2.000000
Array GPU: 3.000000
Array GPU: 4.000000
Array GPU: 5.000000
Array GPU: 6.000000
Array GPU: 7.000000
Array GPU: 8.000000
Array GPU: 9.000000
Array GPU: 10.000000
Array GPU: 11.000000
Array GPU: 12.000000
Array GPU: 13.000000
Array GPU: 14.000000
Array GPU: 15.000000
Array GPU: 16.000000
Array GPU: 17.000000
Array GPU: 18.000000
Array GPU: 19.000000
Array GPU: 20.000000
Array GPU: 21.000000
Array GPU: 22.000000
Array GPU: 23.000000
Array GPU: 24.000000
Array GPU: 25.000000
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 34.000000
Array GPU: 35.000000
Array GPU: 36.000000
Array GPU: 37.000000
Array GPU: 38.000000
Array GPU: 39.000000
Array GPU: 40.000000
Array GPU: 41.000000
Array GPU: 42.000000
Array GPU: 43.000000
Array GPU: 44.000000
Array GPU: 45.000000
Array GPU: 46.000000
Array GPU: 47.000000
Array GPU: 48.000000
Array GPU: 49.000000
Array GPU: 50.000000
Array GPU: 51.000000
Array GPU: 52.000000
Array GPU: 53.000000
Array GPU: 54.000000
Array GPU: 55.000000
Array GPU: 56.000000
Array GPU: 57.000000
Array GPU: 58.000000
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 0.000000     <-------- INCORRECT VALUE, kernel is receiving corrupted memory
Array GPU: 68.000000
Array GPU: 69.000000
...
```

As you can see, incorrect values are received by the device with no apparent pattern, and no error code is returned by *clEnqueueWriteBuffer* function.

To summarize: A memory block is sent to the kernel, but kernel receives zero'ed memory depending on the total block size sent.

The same code tested on different computers behaves differently (incorrect values in different iterations).

How can be memory corruption avoided? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Here](http://pastebin.com/TUmRJDJL)'s the complete working code:

---

**Edit:** After some tests, it needs to be clarify that the problem is not in the *printf*. The problem seems to be in the transfer of data to the device, previous to the execution of the kernel.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Akj8Fvwa)'s the code without the execution of the kernel. The results are still wrong.

Comment: All of this looks like C code, you may want to untag C++ unless you want to receive numerous "dont use malloc, or new, use vector" comments/answers.

Comment: Are you checking the return values of the various OpenCL API calls? You are getting the return values (ret = ...) but then ignoring the value returned. It would be useful to know if one of those functions is failing.

Comment: The return values of every openCL function are printed in the complete working code which is linked at the end of the post. I removed those lines in the piece of code inside the post only to simplify it. However, I checked the return values of every function and in the cases where kernel returns zero (wrong value) none of them returns an error code. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Usually 0 values on a GPU is out-of-bounds memory access.  Run it on the CPU and see if you get a stack overflow?  Check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536033/wavelet-transform-written-in-opencl-seeing-artifacts-in-image/25556191#25556191

Comment: Let me guess, "AMD printf"... is quite known for printing the variable values wrong. Try setting the second address to the value of the first, and reading itfrom CPU. You will find that the operation was OK. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450831/opencl-struct-values-correct-on-cpu-but-not-on-gpu

Comment: @Austin: This is another problem I've found running the code in this computer. It's not recognizing more than one device, the GPU (_Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000_). The CPU model is _i5-3230M CPU @ 2.6GHZ_ and it supports OpenCL, but even with tools like _GPU Caps Viewer_ only one platform with one device, GPU, is recognized. Maybe both problems are related. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @DarkZeros: I just try to assign the value from the first array element to the second one inside the kernel and read it in the host, as you suggest, but the results are the same. Nevertheless, I only add the _cl_amd_printf_ in order to test the code in another computer with an AMD GPU, which interestingly, returns the correct values with every _SizeArray_. The computer I posted the features and results supports _cl_intel_printf_ extension. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Backgroung - Install the AMD OpenCL SDK, it will find the Intel CPU and I often use it anyway for Intel CPUs since it has fewer bugs.

Comment: After writing the buffer try reading it back using clEnqueueReadBuffer into another allocated block of CPU memory. Are the same values 0? If they are correct, this is a problem with the kernel or printf, not writing to the buffer.

Comment: @Austin - When I install the newest driver provided by Dell, Intel CPU was recognized, in addition to GPU. Running the code with this CPU returns the same results: gaps with zero values. I've tried to install _AMD OpenCL SDK_, as you propose, and the code recognizes three different devices, Intel CPU, GPU and, in addition, another Intel CPU. Running the code with this last deice returns an error.

Comment: @Dithermaster - As you proposed, I've tried to write the data to the device with _clEnqueueWriteBuffer_ and read it right after with _clEnqueueReadBuffer_, just before executing the kernel. The results are the same: some of them are zeros depending on the _SizeArray_. The problem seems to be related with the transfer of data to the device with some specific array sizes.

Comment: If you are getting an error on the CPU, I would really think you are accessing memory out of bounds, what is your kernel code and local and global work sizes?

Comment: That is puzzling, especially since now you're seeing the same odd results from two very different devices. For sanity, if where you cout << ArrayOut[0] if you also << Array[0] does it have the correct value or also 0.0?

Comment: @Dithermaster - I've tried what you proposed, and after writing and reading in the buffer, at some array sizes, ArrayOut has zero value but Array has the same value than before.

Comment: @Austin - Since I updated the driver and after installing and uninstalling _AMD OpenCL SDK_, OpenCL recognizes the CPU device, and running the code in it, I get correct results. But in GPU device the results are still wrong. The strange thing is that the same code returns the right results in other computers, and in the same computer running on CPU. If the code is accessing memory out of bounds, should not return wrong results in every device is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
   CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR
```

since your gpu shares same memory with CPU?

Device is also at the same place of host for your iGPU.

Create some buffers, do stress test on them, if all of them get invalid values then install another driver version probably a newer one, if this doesnt solve, RMA your card.

If only a single buffer is erroneous then it is simple vram error , tag that buffer as unusable and create new buffers as necesary and avoid that buffer but Im not sure if driver swaps buffers in background. If every single kernel is malfunctioning then cores may be damaged too.

Comment: I just try to create the buffer adding the flag _CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR_ but the results are the same. In addition, I run the code in two computers with the same hardware and drivers than the one I posted in the first place, and they return also wrong results. The computer is a _Dell Vostro_ with proprietary drivers and the newest update was in 2012. When I installed this newest update the computer begins to recognize CPU in addition to GPU, and running the OpenCL code in CPU the results are correct. GPU still returns wrong and erratic results. Thanks for the answer.